# Count values from different columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
  'home': ['team1', 'team2', 'team3', 'team2'],
  'away': ['team2', 'team3', 'team1', 'team1']
 }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

How can I count the number of time each element (team) appears in both columns ?
The expected result is

```
team1    3
team2    3
team3    2
```

Comment: ``df.stack().value_counts()``. Feels like a dupe; I just can't find the similar question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concatenate the columns and use `.value_counts` method:

```
out = pd.concat([df['home'], df['away']]).value_counts()
```

Output:

```
team1    3
team2    3
team3    2
dtype: int64
```

You can also get the underlying numpy array, `flatten` it, find unique values and their counts, wrap it in a dictionary (this is by far the fastest method):

```
out = dict(np.array(np.unique(df.values.flatten(), return_counts=True)).T)
```

Output:

```
{'team1': 3, 'team2': 3, 'team3': 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

The desired result can be obtained with:

```py
count = df['home'].value_counts() + df['away'].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @sammywemmy mentioned use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `Series` and ten count in [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df[['home', 'away']].stack().value_counts()
```